# Children's book about boy going under the covers and enter a cave and having an adventure

Tags: story-identification, books

Book was borrowed from my then-local library back in the '90s, so '90s or before for publication date.

I remember the crawling under the covers and the cave part vividly, but that's it.

Short, children's book, not chapter book. Illustrated on nearly, if not every, page.